# call that calls result of call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, lambda

Using a framework I need 2 ActiveRecord scopes:

```
scope :tagged_with, lambda { |tag| {:conditions => [" tags like ? ",  "% #{tag} %"] } }
scope :tagged_with_any, lambda { |tag_array | [HERE NEW IMPLEMENTATION] }
```

I want the second scope to be based on the first scope. If you would do it hard coded, you would do for a 2 element array:

```
lambda { | tag_array | tagged_with(tag_array[0]).tagged_with(tag_array[1]) }
```

which works, but how do I do it generic

```
lambda { | tag_array | tags.each { |t| tagged_with(t) } }
```

clearly doesn't do the job.

Comment: what exactly do you want? "tagged_with_any" says ANY, but the concatenation of scopes says ALL.

Comment: any for me meant 'a or b or c is true'

Comment: yes, but if you concatenate scopes you are doing 'a AND b AND c', that's it a "all" operation.

Comment: right, thats why the other test failed... I will do it now by merging the conditions hash. But still your answer was helpful because I have to do match_all too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this acceptable?

```
named_scope :tagged_with_all, lambda { |tag_array| tag_array.inject(self, :tagged_with) }
```

[edit] renamed to `tagged_with_all` since it's what it really does. For a `tagged_with_any`, Vanilla named scopes do not implement OR-concatenations; concatenating ORs conditions "manually" from scopes is doable but a bit messy. Note that you have libraries like Arel or Metawhere.

Comment: thanks, didn't think of this. tried it and results exactly in the expected.